# First ajax call on Phonegap + Zepto returns undefined even after device ready

Tags: ajax, cordova, jsonp, zepto

I'm doing a jsonp call in my mobile app at startup to connect to my server. I'm using Phonegap 2.1 and Zepto 1.0-rc1. At the bottom of my html page, I do the init stuff on DOM ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!$) {$ = Zepto};
$(init);
document.addEventListener('deviceready', Perksea.deviceReady);
</script>
```

...

```
function init() {
    var router = new Backbone.Router();
    ...
}
function deviceReady() {
    isConnected();
    isConnected();
}
function isConnected() {
    $.ajaxJSONP({
        url: 'http://localhost/isconnected',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('response is ' + response);
        }
    });
}
```

The first JSONP call will print "response is undefined" but the second JSONP call works. I've even tried putting the JSONP call in a setTimeout(isConnected, 5000) with the same result. Have already checked that the url is correct etc.

Has anyone seen something like this?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1):

since you are getting into the "success" callback function on the first call (where response is undefined), are you sure that your server is properly responding to the first call? Sounds like it is returning a 200 response, but with no data for that first call.

You can try adding an 'error' callback to see if that provides anything useful as well

```
$.ajaxJSONP({
    url: 'http://localhost/isconnected',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('response is ' + response);
    }
    error: function(response) {
        console.log('error is ' + response);
    }
});
```

Finally, because AJAX is Asynchronous, your 2 calls to *isConnected()* are going to fire one immediately after the other, not waiting for the first to respond. I'm curious what it looks like on the server side (see above).